# Convert string to int with regex and then filter mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I'm trying to get filtered data from my recipes DB. Want to get recipes with less than 30 minutes of cooking time. But the data has text all over it but only one 2 digits number in the whole string. So need to use regex.

I cant get it to work. This code still gets me all the recipes. Even ones with 60 minutes totalTime

```
export async function getServerSideProps() {
    try {
        const client = await clientPromise;
        const db = client.db("recipes");

        const recipes = await db
            .collection("rec")
            .aggregate([
                {
                    $addFields: {
                        totalTimeNumber: {
                            $convert: {
                                input: {
                                    $regexFind: {
                                        input: "$totalTime",
                                        regex: /\d+/,
                                    },
                                },
                                to: "int",
                                onError: 0, // Default value if conversion fails
                                onNull: 0
                            },
                        },
                    },
                },
                { $match: { totalTimeNumber: { $lt: 30 } } }, // Filter recipes with totalTime < 30
                { $sample: { size: 1 } },
            ])
            .toArray();

        return {
            props: { recipes: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(recipes)) },
        };
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }

    return {
        props: { recipes: [] }, // Return an empty array if there's an error
    };
}
```

I tried with match/addfields/regexfind many different combinations.

Comment: `but only one 2 digits number` ... then, strictly speaking, your regex should be `\d{2}` or maybe `\b\d{2}\b`